# Misaligned views in Interface Builder in XCode 8.3

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, xcode8

After updating XCode to the latest version (8.3 [8E162]), I am experiencing some weird behaviour in Interface Builder. More specific, the containers of the UI elements that I have in the storyboard, are misaligned with the rendered controls. When running on device/simulator, everything looks OK.

Any ideas how to fix this?

P.S: I am not using a secondary display, and I have tried to open the storyboard separately and the issue is still there.

[image: XCode Interface Builder Misalignment]

Comment: I have same problem.